# What does it mean ''to be(or not be) emotionally prepared to say or do something''?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does it mean "to be(or not be) emotionally prepared to say or do something"?

I don't really know this very well so I need a explanation of this please

Answer (score 0):

It means ready (or not ready) to do it but referring to your emotional state not any physical preparations that are necessary.
Similar to psyched up

For example, if you had to give a speech, you would be emotionally prepared if you were confident about giving the speech and were prepared mentally for any stress it might cause you. It would not be referring to physical preparations such as whether or not you've written the speech

Comment: If you are not emotionally prepared to say something does it also mean you will say something unexpectedly and unintentionally?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it doesn't? why? then please explain more this

Comment: hello? If you are not emotionally prepared to say something does it also mean you will say something unexpectedly and unintentionally?

Comment: You might say you are not emotionally prepared to say something if you were suddenly told you had to say it. Like giving a speech or bad news to someone. You would not be emotionally prepared because it would be difficult, embarrassing or saddening to do so, even if you knew exactly what you had to say. It doesn't mean that you will accidentally say things that you don't mean to say